# Delete a Stripe Subscription Item using Fetch (Not NPM)

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Trying to delete a stripe subscription item using Fetch method like below

```
export async function update(subItemId, data) {

  const apiKey = "sk_test_XXXXXXXXX"; 

  const response = await fetch("https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_items/" + subItemId, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey
    },
    body: encodeBody(data)
  });

  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    const ret = await response.json();
  let alphastatus = 'approved';
    return {ret, "alphastatus": alphastatus};
}
    let res = await response.json();
  let alphastatus = 'declined';
    return {res, "alphastatus": alphastatus};
}

function encodeBody(data){
  let encoded = "";

  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(data)) {
  encoded = encoded.concat(k,"=", encodeURI(v), "&");
  return encoded; 
  }
}
```

I have tried passing the parameter 'deleted: true' but it returns an error message saying the 'deleted' parameter is not recognized.

Currently I'm trying to send these parameters from my page:

```
let data = {
    "deleted": true,
    "prorate": "false"
};
    update(subItemId, data)
```

I tried following the documentation but I do not understand how to pass DELETE like below

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_items/si_ElRqBpvFaZlfnq \
  -u sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXX: \
  -X DELETE
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the stripe-node library — since you should be writing this code on a backend sever using Node. You should never be running this kind of code accessing the subscriptions API from the frontend(like a browser) and using fetch in that environment, as that means your Stripe secret key would be exposed and compromised.

```
await stripe.subscriptionItems.del(
  subItemId,
  {
    prorate : false
  }
);
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/delete?lang=node

Another way to do this(closer to your original code) is like this:

```
let planToRemove = "plan_EauxYB7fNpQtLn"
let items = subscription.items.data;
items = items.filter(item => item.plan.id == planToRemove)
  .map(item => { return {id: item.id, deleted:true} })
await stripe.subscriptions.update(subscription.id, {
    items : items,
    prorate : false,
});
```

Comment: I am running the api call on the backend. I call the backend function from my page code and then return the response from the api to the page. Is there no way to do it via fetch from the backend? I have issues sending the response back from the api using NPM

Comment: So your `function update` is running on the backend? In that case you really should just use the official stripe-node library for this instead of manually making fetch commands(as it's quite error-prone to find the right parameters), as I suggested.